# Multiple ID forms identifying same resource in RESTful design

Tags: rest, uri

There are a lot of people wondering whether it's OK to have multiple URIs (e.g. `http://example.com/api/colors/red` and `http://example.com/api/palette/red`) refer to the same resource. (The consensus seems to be "yes".)

But I want to know the implications of identifying a resource by multiple *identifiers* in a RESTful interface. (Yes, by implication this would require multiple URIs, but the issue is more than just multiple URIs.)

As an example I'm considering allowing a client to query a color using its name or RGB value. That is the URIs `http://example.com/api/colors/red` and `http://example.com/api/colors/FF0000` would both refer to the color red. Note that the URIs have the same form; merely the resource has two identifiers. Presumably the server would look at whether the identifer was numeric or textual to determine which lookup to do. (Yes, one could be canonical.)

Anyone have any real-world experience with such a scheme in which a URI of the same form uses multiple IDs to refer to the same resource? Does this break any underpinning philosophies of REST?